# showing popupMenu menu on top of everything else

Tags: flutter, dart, popupmenu

I am trying to create a popup menu that can be shown on top of all the other widgets I have on the screen, not something like the dialog but, I need the menu to show on top of a bottom panel of a sliding panel widget.

right now it shows underneath it and clearly is the right beaver from a code perspective, but from a UI perspective that is not good and it does hide some menu options rendering them unTappable, here is pic (a third option in the menu is being blocked) :

[image]

The menu is spawn from the three dots and is positioned exactly on top of them, it usually has 3 options. Right now, since the red bar on the bottom is a slide panel, it is positioned on top of everything and can be slides up from any page, only 2 options appear. my question is how do I make the menu go on top of the red bar, or at least maybe make it open upward instead of downward like it does here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. 
The trick is to use the `rootNavigation`. rootNavigation is available on the `showMenu` method.

```dart
var Choice = await showMenu<ContextMenuOptions>(context: context, position: position,
 items: items, useRootNavigator: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make widget at the top of everything you can use Overlay, but I am not sure it is the best solution for you

Comment: it is not, I can't control the menu directly as a widget.

Comment: What do you use for the bottom panel? Something custom?

Comment: I am using SlidingUpPanel. a package by the same name is found at pub

Comment: Do you use AppBar or block with a popup menu that is put in the body?

Comment: No, not really it is a container with the slidingUP widget, everything else other than that bottom red bar is in the same container

Comment: So problem is that you keep it inside slidingUp panel. If you make research in it`s code you will see the problem. In few words - it used stack and panel has bigger z-index than content